# Put name into a list on the same HTML file with servlet

Tags: java, html, list, servlets

I use a html page with a textfield where you have to enter your name and then click on a login button.
On the same page is a list with all names.
Now I have to send the name by clicking on the login button to a servlet. The servlet have to add the name into the playerlist.

The servlet already receives the entered name but it post it on hole new HTML page. How do I have to change the code so that name will be added to playerlist on the same HTML page not on new page?

```
@WebServlet("/Playerlist")
public class Playerlist extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Playerlist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html><Body>Hallo" + name + "</body></html>");
    out.flush();

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Textfield:

```
<div id= "loginFormular" >
                <form action="Playerlist" method="get" >
                    <label>
                        Name:
                        <input class="textbox" id="loginbox" type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="30">
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input id=buttonLogin class="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Login" name="loginname" />

                    <input id=startButton class="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Start" onclick="showQuestion()" />
                </form>
             </div>
```

Playerlist:

```
<div class="highscore" style="float:right">
            <h4>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Highscore</span>
            </h4>
            <hr/>
            <table id="highscoreTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player</td>
                    <td>Score</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablePlayerlistBody">
           </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
```

I konw there are better ways instead of using a servlet, but I have to it this way.

Comment: can you post html page

Comment: I edited the starting post with the HTML parts

Comment: url-pattern of your serlvet is  `/Playerlist` , your form is using `Playerlist`

Comment: do you mean because of the "/" ? that does not change anything. It still post the the entered name on a new HTML page.

Comment: your page is too static to able to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is too static for what you want to do. I am assuming that you are doing this for practice.

What you are doing is

- submitting your name from a static page.
- Getting the submitted name on servlet side.
- Sending new content to client.

Instead what you need to do is

- Create a dynamic page (JSP) with a text field and list.
- Submit the field value to servlet.
- Receive the value and persist it on server side.  Maintain some type of list on server side and add this value to it and set it on either of the servlet contexts.
- redirect to the same page using request dispatcher and then iterate over the list of values maintained on server side.

Something as below.

**Servlet**

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
serverSideList.add(name );
```

**JSP**

```html
<table id="highscoreTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Player</td>
      <td>Score</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablePlayerlistBody">
    <% for(int i=0 ; i< serverSideList.size(); i++){ %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%=serverSideList.get(i)%>
        </td>
        <td>Some Score</td>
      </tr>
      <%}%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For persisting you can do two things.

- Simple : Maintain server side list in Application Context
- Standard : Persist player detail in database.

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for you help. I got it to work today by my own, and its simular to your answert. Thanks again.